Automatically rename known functions from libraries in IDA
I have a binary file written in c and c++ which uses some libraries. The C/C++ source code of these libraries is publicly accessible online (github). Is there a way in IDA to somehow import this source code, find these functions compiled in the binary and automatically rename them to names used in the source? This would speed up the reverse-engineering process a lot, not having to reverse every function manually.
